# permission denied в docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, golang, docker

Создал простой Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang

EXPOSE 8080 80 443

# Set pwd to the go folder
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    nano

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

COPY ${PROJECT_PATH} /go/cms

RUN cd /go/cms && go build && chmod +x cms

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./cms"]
```

но получаю ошибку

> ERROR: for b5ceea118913_cms_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI
>   runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container
>   process caused "exec: \"./cms\": permission denied": unknown
>
> ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"./cms\": permission denied": unknown

Чего тут не хватает?

```
docker run -it cms_web sh -c "pwd && ls -al"
```

показывает:

```
total 10828
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Feb 28 09:04 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4096 Feb 28 09:04 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root       35 Feb 26 16:24 .env
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root       13 Feb 26 16:24 .env.example
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root     4096 Feb 28 08:06 .git
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       32 Feb 27 08:20 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root     4096 Feb 28 09:03 .idea
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      166 Feb 26 15:56 Database
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      330 Feb 28 09:03 Dockerfile
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root     4096 Feb 27 15:04 _local_mysql_data
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root     4096 Feb 26 12:52 app
-rwsrws--T 1 root root 11025893 Feb 28 09:04 cms
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      940 Feb 27 08:38 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root      384 Feb 26 16:29 main.go
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Feb 28 08:13 migrations
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root     4096 Feb 20 08:26 templates
```

Comment: а PROJECT_PATH нигде не задан. надо либо задать, либо заменить на `.`, скажем. 
сколько раз я натыкался на такие проблемы были связаны с путями или volumes,

Comment: PROJECT_PATH задан в файле .env
если бы проблема была в этом то была бы другая ошибка - файл бы не скомпилировался. Однако файл скомпилировался. cms - это бинарник, которого изначально у меня нет, он создается уже в контейнере.

Answer (score 1):

у вас `WORKDIR` стоит  `${GOPATH}`, не смотря на то, что потом делаете `cd /go/cms`, в конце все равно WORKDIR будет `${GOPATH}`(в данном случае это просто `/go`)

поэтому, вам надо либо указывать полный путь до исполняемого файла `CMD ["/go/cms/cms"]`, либо менять рабочую директорию

```
WORKDIR  /go/cms
CMD ["./cms"]
```

**UPDATE для ответа комментария**

имеем 
main.go

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

docker.env

```
PROJECT_PATH=.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang

# Set pwd to the go folder
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

COPY ${PROJECT_PATH} /go/cms

RUN cd /go/cms \
    && go build \
    && chmod +x cms \
    && ls -al

WORKDIR  /go/cms
CMD ["./cms"]
```

билдим

```
docker build -t test  -f Dockerfile .
```

исполняем

```
➜  docker run -it test
hello world
```

из Dockerfile удаляем `WORKDIR  /go/cms`, билдим, исполняем и получаем

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"./cms\": permission denied": unknown.

потому что нет исполняемого файла. как убедиться?

```
docker run -it test  sh -c "pwd && ls -al "

/go
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Feb 28 09:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb 28 09:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 03:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb 28 09:25 cms
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 28 09:25 pkg
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Feb 28 09:25 src
```

Ч.т.д.

Comment: Нет, в предыдущем коменте написано почему это не так. Файл находит. если поменять WORKDIR то выводится уже  no such file or directory, так что путь там правильный и файл находит.

Comment: я обновил вопрос, там в действительности путь не правильный и файл не может быть найден. просто укажите `CMD ["/go/cms/cms"]`

Comment: Я пробовал ставить ls - файл есть. Если бы его не было то было бы no such file or directory а не permission denied

Comment: соберите ваш image. исполните `docker run -it your-image  sh -c "pwd && ls -al "`. что показывает?

Comment: @JonnyManowar попробовали? что пишет?

Comment: Да вот в вопросе дописал

Comment: Сейчас компьютер перезапустил и вроде заработало, но теперь порт недоступен, хотя когда локально запускаю то оно подключается к базе которая так же в докере запущена

Comment: вижу выхлоп. но вы поменяли на полный путь или на workdir? 
проблема с запуском решилось?

Comment: Ну путь там полный как был так и есть

Comment: Вроде работает - файл компилирует и запускает но вот теперь бинарник сразу после запуска обрывает работу, ошибок никаких не выдает, хотя локально он у меня слушает указаный порт.

Comment: во время билда бинарь ничего не выдает. нужно запускать из этого собранного image. вы же так делаете? `docker run -it your-image `

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает при запуске контейнера, потому что внутри него нет прав на запуск файла ./cms. Это происходит потому, что в Dockerfile необходимо изменить права на файл cms командой chmod, чтобы его можно было запустить внутри контейнера.

Вот что нужно добавить в Dockerfile перед запуском файла ./cms:

```
RUN chmod +x /go/cms/cms
```

Эта команда изменит права на файл cms и позволит запустить его внутри контейнера.

Полный Dockerfile должен выглядеть так:

```
FROM golang

EXPOSE 8080 80 443

# Set pwd to the go folder
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    nano

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

COPY ${PROJECT_PATH} /go/cms

RUN cd /go/cms && go build && chmod +x cms && \
    chmod +x /go/cms/cms

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./cms"]
```

Comment: а чем, по-вашему, команда `cd /go/cms && chmod +x cms` отличается от `chmod +x /go/cms/cms`?